# jquery find div or select by name returning 0 results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select a `<div>` inside of a `<p>` by name, but it's returning 0 results.  The same type of selection works fine for `<input>` and `<span>`, but not for `<select>` and `<div>`.  The code below demonstrates what I mean:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="foo">
        <input type="text" name="tl-label" />
        <select name="tl_type">
            <option value="select_type">Select type</option>
            <option value="field">Field</option>
            <option value="text">Text label</option>
            <option value="flag_set">Flag set</option>
        </select>
        <span name="manip-links">
            <a name="move_up" href="#">[move up]</a>
            <a name="move_down" href="#">[move down]</a>
            <a name="delete" href="#">[delete]</a>
        </span>
        <div name="field-params">
            field params
        </div>
        <div name="text-params">
            text params
        </div>
        <div name="flag-set-params">
            flag set params
        </div>
    </p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!--
    var foo = $('#foo');
    foo.tl_label = foo.find('input[name=tl-label]');
    foo.tl_type = foo.find('select[name=tl-type]');
    foo.manip_links = foo.find('span[name=manip-links]');
    foo.field_params = foo.find('div[name=field-params]');
    foo.text_params = foo.find('div[name=text-params]');
    foo.flag_set_params = foo.find('div[name=flag-set-params]');

    $('body').append('<p>' +
        'tl_label: ' + foo.tl_label.size() + '<br/>' +
        'tl_type: ' + foo.tl_type.size() + '<br/>' +
        'manip_links: ' + foo.manip_links.size() + '<br/>' +
        'field_params: ' + foo.field_params.size() + '<br/>' +
        'text_params: ' + foo.text_params.size() + '<br/>' +
        'flag_set_params: ' + foo.flag_set_params.size() + '<br/>' +
        '</p>');
//-->
</script>
</html>
```

The traces appended at the bottom read (in Firefox 3.5.6):

tl_label: 1
tl_type: 0
manip_links: 1
field_params: 0
text_params: 0
flag_set_params: 0

They should all read 1.  What am I missing?

Comment: You should probably pick either dash (`-`) **or** underscore (`_`) as a word seperator as using both seems to have confused you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a dash instead of an underscore in your code inside the names. (Or an underscore instead of a dash in the "select" element name; one or the other :-)

Also, div elements can't have a name attribute, I don't think.  Use "id" and select with "#whatever".

Comment: I don't believe I got dash versus underscore mixed up at the logical level.  My problem was using the name attribute where it can't be used.  My goal was to dynamically generate HTML elements, and I found a rather interesting way to do it: use a hidden template in HTML, copy it per instance, and extract/remove IDs and use them as keys to refer to instance elements.

Comment: Well in the example code you posted, the select element has a "name" attribute of "tl_type", but in your code you look for "select[name=tl-type]" in that call to "find". An underscore in the first one, and a dash in the second one.